# oracle 11g R2 32 bit - SQL developer not opening on windows 11 Home

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, windows-11

I installed oracle enterprise 11g R2 on windows 11 home single language.
Now trying to open SQL developer says `'Unable to launch the Java Virtual Machine located at path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll'`.

Once I tried installing same oracle on windows 10 home but could not due to error. Later I came to know Oracle Enterprise is not supported on Windows 10 Home. This time however, there was no error as such except typical installation option was marked in red. Otherwise installation was complete. So I was hoping Windows 11 home would work.

In case, the problem is not to be solved, is there any oracle edition that is supported on windows 11 home. Objective here is to make small scale projects to learn nitty gritties of SQL thouroughly.

Thank you!

Comment: You have Java installed on your PC - and that version (or later), and in that location? If you have a different version/path then you can tell SQL Developer where to find it. Otherwise you will need to install it. You can also [download the latest version](https://www.oracle.com/database/sqldeveloper/technologies/download/) of SQL Developer independently of the Oracle database software, optionally including the JDK..

Comment: HI Alex, I installed Java and then tried to do mentioned operation and failed. However, after installing netbeans (which I never use), suddenly SQL developer has start to work. Though my problem is solved, actual reason for the problem is still unknown to me.

Comment: The version and path it's installed under would matter. It sounds like you installed it somewhere else; and perhaps Netbeans installed its own version which happened to be in the place SQL Developer was looking. (Maybe you had installed it before which registered the JDK path, and then removed it; then reinstallation 'just worked'?) Anyway, this question probably isn't going to be much help to anyone else either.

Comment: The Oracle installation directory must not contain any spaces `C:\Program Files (x86)`. Install it into a different folder, e.g. `c:\Oralce`, usually you should have got an error while installation.